# quotation ruining json encode

Tags: php, json

I have this problem when data has a quotation, ('), it's ruiningg the JSdata which now I cannot fetch. is there any way to prevent this?

[image]

the ' in Haven't ruined the data.

Comment: try to use single quotes?
```data-payload='<json>'```

Comment: i'm using json_encode to turn it into json

Comment: and also, im using single quotes for data-payload

Comment: Hard to tell what your setup is, but this would work: `data-test="<?= htmlentities(json_encode($test)); ?>"` - that will escape double quotes.

Comment: Please also read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)